# How to find the variables I created in Pycharm variable explorer?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to use the variable explorer in PyCharm.
I click on python console and I have a window for the variables.
However, the variables that I created in my code do not appear, only built in variables appear. (Under special variables, there is: **builtins** and sys)

Where can I find the variables that appear in my code?

The specific variable I'm looking for is a dictionary called "data_model".
It is created within the program and filled during runtime.

Comment: use debugger, there you will get the variable, else if you want to see full use spyder ide

Answer (score 0):

You can run the code in python console and then you will be able to see all the variables (along side builtin variables). By default it will only show builtin and sys variables and as you run the code in python console, it will show the variables.

The dictionary view is not great I think but in pandas dataframe you will be able to right click on variable and click on 'view as a dataframe' which puts the dataframe in a new window.